# How do I convert this complex nested Dict into Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, csv

I want to transform the result of a call from an API into a data frame. The result of the API call is a nested dictionary, but I am unable to produce a data frame.

In addition to json_normalize, I tried pd.DataFrame.from_dict. However, until now had been unsuccessful. I also tried to flatten the dictionary, but nothing.

I used the following call:

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
result = response.json()
```

And the output was:

```
{'mlcSongCode': 'A6457V',
 'primaryTitle': 'AIR FORCE ONES',
 'membersSongId': '',
 'artists': 'TRACK | NELLY, MURPHY LEE, ALI, KYJUAN, TRACK BOYZ',
 'propertyId': None,
 'akas': [{'akaId': '', 'akaTitle': '', 'akaTitleTypeCode': ''}],
 'writers': [{'writerId': '1083561',
   'writerLastName': 'SMITH',
   'writerFirstName': 'PREMRO VONZELLAIRE',
   'writerIPI': '00232478669',
   'writerRoleCode': 'ComposerLyricist',
   'chainId': 'PSC_337535223',
   'chainParentId': ''},
  {'writerId': '1858916',
   'writerLastName': 'GOODWIN',
   'writerFirstName': 'MARLON',
   'writerIPI': '',
   'writerRoleCode': 'ComposerLyricist',
   'chainId': 'PSC_337535224',
   'chainParentId': ''},
  {'writerId': '1883205',
   'writerLastName': 'HAYNES',
   'writerFirstName': 'CORNELL',
   'writerIPI': '',
   'writerRoleCode': 'ComposerLyricist',
   'chainId': 'PSC_337535225',
   'chainParentId': ''},
  {'writerId': '4733138',
   'writerLastName': 'LAVELLE',
   'writerFirstName': 'CRUMP',
   'writerIPI': '',
   'writerRoleCode': 'ComposerLyricist',
   'chainId': 'PSC_337535226',
   'chainParentId': ''}],
 'publishers': [{'publisherId': '910354',
   'mlcPublisherNumber': None,
   'publisherName': 'TENYOR MUSIC',
   'publisherIpiNumber': '00263286262',
   'publisherRoleCode': 'OriginalPublisher',
   'collectionShare': 16.67,
   'chainId': 'PSA_311720187',
   'chainParentId': 'PSC_311915511',
   'administrators': [],
   'parentPublishers': [{'publisherId': '377508',
     'mlcPublisherNumber': None,
     'publisherName': 'ALL MY PUBLISHING LLC',
     'publisherIpiNumber': '',
     'publisherRoleCode': 'OriginalPublisher',
     'collectionShare': 0,
     'chainId': 'PSC_311915511',
     'chainParentId': 'PSC_337535223|PSC_337535224|PSC_337535225|PSC_337535226',
     'administrators': [],
     'parentPublishers': []}]},
  {'publisherId': '716372',
   'mlcPublisherNumber': None,
   'publisherName': 'KOBALT MUSIC PUB AMERICA INC',
   'publisherIpiNumber': '00503659557',
   'publisherRoleCode': 'SubPublisher',
   'collectionShare': 50,
   'chainId': 'PSA_365023093',
   'chainParentId': 'PSC_337535222',
   'administrators': [],
   'parentPublishers': [{'publisherId': '631204',
     'mlcPublisherNumber': None,
     'publisherName': 'TARPO MUSIC PUB.',
     'publisherIpiNumber': '00419823444',
     'publisherRoleCode': 'OriginalPublisher',
     'collectionShare': 0,
     'chainId': 'PSC_337535222',
     'chainParentId': '',
     'administrators': [],
     'parentPublishers': []}]}],
 'iswc': ''}
```

Then to produce the data frame, I used the following code:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(result)
# df = pd.read_json(result)
print(df)
```

But had an error

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'json_normalize'
```

My main goal is to convert this into Excel or CSV format so that it is properly readable.

Comment: Is your pandas installed and imported properly? When I run your code, it returns the dataframe as expected

Comment: @RayA.
`df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result, orient='index')`
`df = df.transpose()`

I tried to run this it worked but all the values are clustered. 
I want each key to be a column and each value associated with it.

Comment: When I run `df = pd.json_normalize(result)`, I get a dataframe with each key of the `result` dictionary as a column, with the value of the corresponding key as the value of the cell.  Do you mean you're trying to get each key of the nested dictionary as columns as well?

Comment: Also to clarify, in the `writers` key of the result, there are multiple dictionaries. Do you want each of individual writers on one column each?

Comment: I tried to reinstall pandas but I still have the same error message. `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'json_normalize'`

Comment: Yes, I want all the writers, and publishers in each column. So each and every key is in a separate column.

Comment: What's your pandas version?

Comment: pandas           : 0.25.1

Comment: That's an older version of pandas. In 0.25, the module is at pandas.io.json.json_normalize, so you will need to import it with `from pandas.io.json import json_normalize`, then call `json_normalize(result)` instead of `pd.json_normalize(result)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the results dictionary

```
result = {'mlcSongCode': 'A6457V',
 'primaryTitle': 'AIR FORCE ONES',
 'membersSongId': '',
 'artists': 'TRACK | NELLY, MURPHY LEE, ALI, KYJUAN, TRACK BOYZ',
 'propertyId': None,
 'akas': [{'akaId': '', 'akaTitle': '', 'akaTitleTypeCode': ''}],
 'writers': [{'writerId': '1083561',
   'writerLastName': 'SMITH',
   'writerFirstName': 'PREMRO VONZELLAIRE',
   'writerIPI': '00232478669',
   'writerRoleCode': 'ComposerLyricist',
   'chainId': 'PSC_337535223',
   'chainParentId': ''},
  {'writerId': '1858916',
   'writerLastName': 'GOODWIN',
   'writerFirstName': 'MARLON',
   'writerIPI': '',
   'writerRoleCode': 'ComposerLyricist',
   'chainId': 'PSC_337535224',
   'chainParentId': ''},
  {'writerId': '1883205',
   'writerLastName': 'HAYNES',
   'writerFirstName': 'CORNELL',
   'writerIPI': '',
   'writerRoleCode': 'ComposerLyricist',
   'chainId': 'PSC_337535225',
   'chainParentId': ''},
  {'writerId': '4733138',
   'writerLastName': 'LAVELLE',
   'writerFirstName': 'CRUMP',
   'writerIPI': '',
   'writerRoleCode': 'ComposerLyricist',
   'chainId': 'PSC_337535226',
   'chainParentId': ''}],
 'publishers': [{'publisherId': '910354',
   'mlcPublisherNumber': None,
   'publisherName': 'TENYOR MUSIC',
   'publisherIpiNumber': '00263286262',
   'publisherRoleCode': 'OriginalPublisher',
   'collectionShare': 16.67,
   'chainId': 'PSA_311720187',
   'chainParentId': 'PSC_311915511',
   'administrators': [],
   'parentPublishers': [{'publisherId': '377508',
     'mlcPublisherNumber': None,
     'publisherName': 'ALL MY PUBLISHING LLC',
     'publisherIpiNumber': '',
     'publisherRoleCode': 'OriginalPublisher',
     'collectionShare': 0,
     'chainId': 'PSC_311915511',
     'chainParentId': 'PSC_337535223|PSC_337535224|PSC_337535225|PSC_337535226',
     'administrators': [],
     'parentPublishers': []}]},
  {'publisherId': '716372',
   'mlcPublisherNumber': None,
   'publisherName': 'KOBALT MUSIC PUB AMERICA INC',
   'publisherIpiNumber': '00503659557',
   'publisherRoleCode': 'SubPublisher',
   'collectionShare': 50,
   'chainId': 'PSA_365023093',
   'chainParentId': 'PSC_337535222',
   'administrators': [],
   'parentPublishers': [{'publisherId': '631204',
     'mlcPublisherNumber': None,
     'publisherName': 'TARPO MUSIC PUB.',
     'publisherIpiNumber': '00419823444',
     'publisherRoleCode': 'OriginalPublisher',
     'collectionShare': 0,
     'chainId': 'PSC_337535222',
     'chainParentId': '',
     'administrators': [],
     'parentPublishers': []}]}],
 'iswc': ''}
```

Load it into a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.json_normalize(result)
```

This gives a dataframe with each key of results as a column, and the value of the key as the column value. In this case, the columns are   `mlcSongCode     primaryTitle    membersSongId   artists     propertyId  akas    writers     publishers  iswc`

Explode the `writers` column:

```
df = df.explode('writers').reset_index(drop=True)
```

This converts each element in the `writers` array into a row, giving you a dataframe with one row for each 'writer'

Normalize the `writers` JSON into a flat table. This takes the JSON for each 'writer' and expands each key of it into a column. E.g. it will generate a column for 'writerLastName', 'writerFirstName' etc

```
normalized = pd.json_normalize(df['writers'])
```

Join the normalized dataframe to the original dataframe, and remove the original 'writers' column:

```
df = df.join(normalized).drop(columns=['writers'])
```

Then repeat with the other JSON columns as needed